# Using request HTTP client library to post to FastSpring API

Tags: javascript, api, request

I am attempting to use [request](https://github.com/request/request) to POST to FastSpring's API for updating subscriptions for my customers. I am able to GET subscriptions without problem, but when it comes to POST, I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```js
      var options = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'https://api.fastspring.com/subscriptions',
          headers: {
              'Authorization': auth,
              'User-Agent': 'request',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          formData : {
              'subscriptions': [
                  {
                      "subscription": subscriptionId,
                      "quantity": newQty,
                      "product": product,
                      "prorate": true
                  }
              ]
          }
          
      };
         
      request.post(options, function (error, response, body) {
          _logger.error('Fastspring API response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
          _logger.error('Fastspring API error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
          _logger.error('Fastspring API body: ' + JSON.stringify(body));
          if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
              res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(body));
          } else {
              _logger.error('Fastspring API Error: ' + error);
              res.status(500).send({ 'error':  error});
          }
      });
```

The result of attempting the POST results in the following error:

```
TypeError: source.on is not a function
```

I looked it up and saw that the reason why it was failing is that request cannot accept the formData I'm sending. Problem is that without it, I cannot POST to FastSpring's API (I get the error message "subscriptions not found." if I send anything else).

**My question is this**: Can I send my formData in any way that will be accepted by request? I've looked this issue up on the issues page of request and couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to pass some JSON data? Usually that kind of data are written in body not in formData.

Try something like this:

```
var myreq = request.post(...)
myreq.write(myJsonData);
myreq.end();
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. For anyone who sees this in the future, the JSON data needs to be stringified to be sent properly (JSON.stringify(myJsonData) in this case). Thanks, @mligor!